# strtotime instead of this very long function?

Tags: php, date, format

I am digging in the code this professional programmer had put together for an events website for me and I found this function that seems super confusing, as it looks like 1 line of code with `"strtotime"` would do the same thing.

Is it because we wanted to use `"Jan 2nd"` format with the two letters after the day of the month?

```
function convert_date_to_web($date) {
    if (empty($date) || $date == "0000-00-00") return $date;
    switch ($date[5].$date[6]) {
        case '01':
        $month = 'Jan';
        break;
        case '02':
        $month = 'Feb';
        break;
        case '03':
        $month = 'Mar';
        break;
        case '04':
        $month = 'Apr';
        break;
        case '05':
        $month = 'May';
        break;
        case '06':
        $month = 'Jun';
        break;
        case '07':
        $month = 'Jul';
        break;
        case '08':
        $month = 'Aug';
        break;
        case '09':
        $month = 'Sep';
        break;
        case '10':
        $month = 'Oct';
        break;
        case '11':
        $month = 'Nov';
        break;
        case '12':
        $month = 'Dec';
    }
    if($date[9] == "1") {
        $day = $date[9]."st";
    }
    else if ($date[9] == "2") {
        $day = $date[9]."nd";
    }
    else if ($date[9] == "3") {
        $day = $date[9]."rd";
    }
    else {
        $day = $date[9]."th";
    }
    if($date[8] != "0") {
        $day = $date[8].$day;
    }
    $date = $month." ".$day.", ".$date[0].$date[1].$date[2].$date[3];
    return $date;
}
```

And my version is

```
$timestamp = strtotime($event->start_date);
$start_date = date("M d, Y", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Can you find any examples where your code works and theirs does not (or vice versa?). If they're interchangeable, go with yours I guess. Just because someone is a pro doesn't mean they always do everything the best way, right!

Comment: That paragraph about months could be shortened to even `$month_names[((int) $date[5].$date[6])]` (*given a 1-based array of month names, of course*)

Comment: Is it just me, or is the long version going to spit out things like "Sep 11st"?

Comment: Most professional programmer began programming from the time you should do everything from very base.

Comment: @Hammerite - [Yes](http://codepad.viper-7.com/POXmZc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an exact replicate of the original function. I've used two versions, the first uses strtotime, the second uses explode to avoid using strtotime.

```
$date = '2011-10-01';
$date_format = 'M jS, Y'; // Three letter month, day name w/o leading zero, day suffix, year
echo date( $date_format, strtotime( $date)) . "\n";

$date_pieces = explode( '-', $date);
echo date( $date_format, mktime( 0, 0, 0, $date_pieces[1], $date_pieces[2], $date_pieces[0]));
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VXAUm8)

Answer (score 0):

Yup. I think that is what the reason for that long function is. It is to add in the "st", "nd", "rd", and the "th".

Your code does not do that. Maybe you can try it this way? (Needs debugging, cos i never tested it on actual php)

```
$timestamp = strtotime($event->start_date);
$start_date = date("M d", $timestamp);
$lastNum = substr($start_date, -1)
switch($lastNum) {
  case "0":
    break;
  case "1":
    $start_date .= "st"; break;
  case "2":
    $start_date .= "nd"; break;
  case "3":
    $start_date .= "rd"; break;
  default:
    $start_date .= "th"; break;
}
$start_date .= date(", Y", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I prefer such explode()ish solutions over strtotime(), too, is that they give deterministic, portable results that are less [surprising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_surprise) while strtotime() does some complex magic.

Answer (score 0):

As with all programming there is more than one way to do something. Experience teaches programmer to do things a certain way. From the look of this this function if for converting the default output format of mysql dates into a version that converts the month to a string. It looks good to me